# Is there a way to change this code to have it only output possible numbers that add up to 15?

Tags: vb.net

For a computer science homework, with the example of money, I need to print all possible combination of numbers that add up to 15. I have 9 coins of 1GBP, 3 coins of 2GBP and 3 banknotes of 5GBP. The code below does all possible combinations but I only need to print ones where the numbers add up to 15.
Here is the code below.

```vb
        Dim num(15) As Integer
        Dim a%, b%, c%, d%, e%, f%, g%, h%, i%, j%, k%, l%, m%, n%, o%

        num(1) = 1
        num(2) = 1
        num(3) = 1
        num(4) = 1
        num(5) = 1
        num(6) = 1
        num(7) = 1
        num(8) = 1
        num(9) = 1
        num(10) = 2
        num(11) = 2
        num(12) = 2
        num(13) = 5
        num(14) = 5
        num(15) = 5
        Dim count As Integer


        For a = 0 To 14
            For b = 0 To 14
                For c = 0 To 14
                    For d = 0 To 14
                        For e = 0 To 14
                            For f = 0 To 14
                                For g = 0 To 14
                                    For h = 0 To 14
                                        For i = 0 To 14
                                            For j = 0 To 14
                                                For k = 0 To 14
                                                    For l = 0 To 14
                                                        For m = 0 To 14
                                                            For n = 0 To 14
                                                                For o = 0 To 14

                                                                    Console.WriteLine(num(a) & num(b) & num(c) & num(d) & num(e) & num(f) & num(g) & num(h) & num(i) & num(j) & num(k) & num(l) & num(m) & num(n) & num(o))

                                                                    count += 1

                                                                Next o
                                                            Next n
                                                        Next m
                                                    Next l
                                                Next k
                                            Next j
                                        Next i
                                    Next h
                                Next g
                            Next f
                        Next e
                    Next d
                Next c
            Next b
        Next a
```

Comment: There are alternative solutions you can follow, but answering your question of checking the sum, you are half way there. Add all the numbers together (just before `Console.WriteLine()`) in a `sum` variable. You can then check if `sum` is equal to `15` and if yes print out the combo.

Comment: Thanks for the info. One thing I forgot to put is that I needed to use nested loops for the homework so i couldn't do it differently.